# Tableau - Dynamic Datasets

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm not sure what what best way would be to describe the problem I'm trying to solve.

Basically, my datasets are a model output which are generated in the same format on the daily basis.
I have build a dashboard around one dataset but want to create a dynamic filter which check for the output files in a folder and update visuals for the dataset I select.

I can create data connections for the existing datasets and that will make it work but since the datasets get updated on daily basis, is there a way to create such a filter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to let the user select any arbitrary data source without knowing the choices in advance.   Maybe there is a way. But maybe you don't need to do that.

Suppose you generate new datasets each day and they are always called by the same names, such as data-monday, data-tuesday, data-wednesday, etc.    So you  always have exactly the same seven datasets to pick from.

Then each dataset could have a field in it corresponding to the name, such as "WHAT-SET" with values, say, "monday", "tuesday', "wednesday", etc.

Then your data step could import all seven data sets and UNION them together, and your user could use a parameter to filter on "WHAT-SET" to pick the desired one.